# Issue with accessing subscriptions in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, subscriptions

I'm getting frustrated at an 'Exception in template helper' error in a Meteor application I'm trying to develop.

In /lib/collections.js I have:

```
Categories = new Meteor.Collection("categories");
Venues = new Meteor.Collection("venues");
VenuesAndUsers = new Meteor.Collection("venuesAndUsers");
```

In /server/main.js I have:

```
Meteor.publish("Categories", function () {
    return Categories.find({}, {sort: {order: 1}});
});
Meteor.publish("Venues", function () {
    return Venues.find();
});
Meteor.publish("VenuesForUser", function () {
    return VenuesAndUsers.find();
});
```

In /lib/router.js I have:

```
Router.configure({
    // Other stuff

    waitOn: function() {
        return [
            Meteor.subscribe('Categories'),
            Meteor.subscribe('Venues'),
            Meteor.subscribe('VenuesForUser'),
        ];
    }
});
```

In /client/templates/list.html I have:

```
{{#each xzz}}
    {{name}} - {{id}}<br />
{{/each}}

{{#each venues}}
    {{venueId}} - {{userId}}<br />
{{/each}}
```

In /client/templates/list.js I have:

```
venues: function() {
    return VenuesForUser.find();
},
xzz: function() {
    return Venues.find();
}
```

My output is:

```
Venue 1 - Venue 1 id
Venue 2 - Venue 2 id
...
```

And in the javascript console, I get:

```
Exception in template helper: .venues@http://localhost:3000/app/client/templates/list.js?2a82ae373ca11b4e9e171649f881c6ab1f8ed69b:11:7
bindDataContext/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?695c7798b7f4eebed3f8ce0cbb17c21748ff8ba8:2994:14
...
```

Now, my issue is that my publishing 'VenuesFoUser' generates the error above when trying to access its contents.

But, why!?

Edit: If I change all instances of 'VenuesForUser' to 'VenuesAndUsers' the subscription works. But how does that make sense? Can I only give names to subscriptions that match collections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Publications publish documents to your collections. A publication can be named `random`, but if it returns a cursor from a collection named `NotRandom`, then that's the collection they get published to on the client.

You have a publication named `VenuesForUser`, which returns a cursor from the collection `VenuesAndUsers`. On the client side, `VenuesAndUsers` is the collection that has the data that was published from the server. So you can only do `VenuesAndUsers.find()`, since there is no collection named `VenuesForUser`. The publication name has no effect on anything else - it's just a name. It doesn't create a new collection for you.

I hope I made it clear.

Comment: Are you saying that, whatever the name of my publication (and thus subscription), the collection that needs to be queried (on the client) remains the collection on which the subscription was based?

Comment: @MastaBaba Yes. The publication name only has significance in the initial subscribe phase. When you first subscribe, the client says to the server `Hey! I would like to subscribe to "VenuesForUser"`. Once that is done, the message that is sent from the "VenuesForUser" publication is `Documents A and B were added to the collection "VenuesAndUsers"`. The client receives the message and adds documents A and B to the collection `VenuesAndUsers`.

Comment: @MastaBaba Also, I really like [this article on DDP](https://meteorhacks.com/introduction-to-ddp). If you haven't read it yet, I'd recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be, not Meteor, but Mongo, such as:

```
Platypi = new Mongo.Collection('platypi');
```

not:

```
Platypi = new Meteor.Collection('platypi');
```

Comment: Hmmm. The latter is definitely working for me, though.

Comment: Interesting; the former works for me, and that's how I've seen it documented, so I'm a bit surprised that both work.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon `Meteor.Collection` used to be the way to define collections. [It was changed to `Mongo.Collection`, but the change was backwards-compatible.](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/53a1c013c78432d403dcdf2417b0368bd1c0f72b/History.md#backwards-compatible-renames) So yes, `Mongo.Collection` is what you should use, but `Meteor.Collection` still works (but might not at some point in the future!)