# Problems when publishing users into other collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, collections

I´m storing userIDs of the friends in my 'profile.friends' as an array in every user document:

```
...

"profile" : {
                "friends" : [
                        "LminJPr2mC2YBB9YX"
                ]
        }

...
```

I have a Friends Collection where I would like to have all the user data of my friends.

I published it like:

```
Meteor.publish('friends', function () {
    let friendslist = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId}).profile.friends;
    console.log(friendslist);
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: {$in: friendslist}});
});
```

My problem is that on the client the Friends collection is always empty. Instead of publishing them into the Friends collection the Friends are available in the Meteor.users Collection but I only need them in the Friends collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this question is already answered successfully, so I won't address the exact issue you raised. However, there are two points worth making.

(1) I would recommend storing friend information in a separate collection. This will make your code simpler and improve its performance. For example, when a user adds (or removes) a friend, all you'll have to do is insert (or delete) a document in the collection rather than reading, modifying, and updating an array in a user document. A document in this collection could look something like:

```
{
  _id: <auto generated Mongo id>
  fromUserId: <id of user doing the friending>,
  toUserId: <id of user being friended>
}
```

(2) Note that you probably don't want to publish all the details of a user record. If you just want to publish username and profile, for example, you could do this:

```
var query = {_id: { $in: friendslist } };
var options = { fields: { username: 1, profile: 1 } };
return Meteor.users.find( query, options );
```

Comment: This is the proper way to go about the problem. OP should consider this answer.

Answer (score 2):

I answered a similar question recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33177382/issue-with-accessing-subscriptions-in-meteor/33177959#33177959):

> Publications publish documents to your collections. A publication can be named `random`, but if it returns a cursor from a collection named `NotRandom`, then that's the collection they get published to on the client.

To solve your problem, you can use the methods `added`, `changed`, `removed` provided in the [`publish`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) function. E.g:

```
Meteor.publish('friends', function () {
    let collectionName = 'friends';
    let friendslist = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId}).profile.friends;
    Meteor.users.find({_id: {$in: friendslist}}).forEach((friend) => {
        this.added(collectionName, friend._id, friend);
    });
});
```

This would just publish all the users to the collection `friends`. If you want to make it reactive, take a look at the example in the documentation I linked above. You would have to use `observeChanges()` on the cursor.